Trying to find out what kind of frame I have


disc brake caliper mount



distinctive FEATURE



single chainring



bevelled headset



Whole bike

It has a bevelled head set and one chainring.
The Serial number is OB210122878. The first digit I think is 0, it's got a slash through it but is different than the obvious B and 8 found in the serial number.

Welcome to the site.  Serial numbers aren't any use here, instead post some clear and well lit photos.  At this stage all we know is that it might be a BMX based on your username.

piling on, but yes, rarely are serial numbers any good to identify a bike.  Post some pictures and we have a chance of helping.

Also the frame is very light and non-ferrous.

Try putting a magnet on the top tube and see if it sticks.  If yes, its steel.  If no its probably aluminium.

From the first 4 photos, this is a 1-by mountain bike with a derailleur-based rear gearset.
I was wrong in the comment, it is not a BMX.
I see an empty rear disk brake mount which also means its not a BMX - they always have rim brakes or a coaster.
There is no fork, and no wheels so you have a bare frame.  It won't be a rideable bike without additional parts.

Two wheels with disk brake rotor mounts, maybe 26" or possibly another size.
Cassette
Rear derailleur
Probably a new chain
Probably new inner cables for gears and brakes
Two brake calipers
Two brake levers
Fork
Handlebar and stem
Gear shifters
Grips
Saddle and Seatpost

It could be a useful bike, but give it a good wash and look for cracks or damage before buying other parts.

The head tube is not "bevelled" - instead I'd call it barrel-shaped and probably hydroformed or made in a press.   This allows the frame maker to use a wider tube for the head tube, and provides a wider place for the down/top tube welds.  This will add strength and stiffness at the cost of weight.  Not really an advantage because the headset bearings are still relatively small; this is a cost-saving design.
As for identification, it looks like a common east-asian frame made in bulk and has no specific redeeming features.  If you like it, by all means ride it.  This is not a valuable museum piece.
There's nothing wrong with you hand-lettering  "HUFFTY" on the side, or get a couple of decals cut out to say the same.  After all the work you'll be doing, it may as well be named for its owner+rider.
If you do assemble this bike to a rideable state, please do post a photo and describe how you got on.

I am debating on switching frames. I have a heavier rover frame that rides excellent, but a bit heavy. Bunny hopping up on curbs is boarder line comfortable. I'd rather exert less energy on such common task.

The answer above hits all the points you need to know except one. The plate between the chain stays is a kickstand mount, something you will not find on quality bikes. With the price of vintage MTB's these days, don't bother with that BSO frame.
